# Security Camera Device Driver

Tags: drivers, usb, camera

I have an Autoguard (Liteline?) security camera that connects to a PC via a 2.4GHz GMSR Receiver. The receiver has a USB connector.

When I plug the receiver into my laptop running Ubuntu 17.10, it is not recognised (that I can tell anyways). Any suggestions for how I can figure how to get the Camera/Receiver to work with Ubuntu such as 
- how to figure out which devices are connected
- site to check for device drivers
- other advice?
Bill

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Try `lsusb` to see how the device shows itself to Ubuntu.  sorry I can't help beyond that (though camera software I'd hope would recognize the device)

Comment: In a terminal window, type `journalctl --follow`, then connect the camera's receiver.  After it settles down, `^C` the `journalctl` command, then analyze the log messages.

Comment: @guiverc - thanks for the suggestion. I did show the device which apparently is of the 'TV Tuner' genre and not a camera device.

Comment: @waltinator - Your suggestion threw additional light on the problem. And I have now descended into the Linux TV support 'rabbit hole' of trying to trouble shoot device drivers and TV Tuner setup. It may be that I need a specific firmware driver, xc3028? to get to at least the next step.  This I determined from the crash logs when I tried to start tvtime (Seg Fault).  If I find out more I will try to post any further insights. Thanks again